# How to make the LDAP filter to find value in three levels of OU

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Sorry I am new to `LDAP`/`AD` service, I have a problem to make up an easy 3 or 4 level `LDAP` query for the server, assume the hierarchy is like this:

```
DN my.com.app (dc=my,dc=com,dc=app)
   |_OU maingroup
       |_OU subgroup
           |_OU grandsongroup
```

I try to grab all the value defined in grandsongroupwith current log in user (assume username is `worker`), so here is my filter

```
filter = "(&(ou=grandsongroup,ou=subgroup,ou=maingroup)(sAMAccountName=worker"))";
```

but it returns nothing, what could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The filter string doesn't define the depth of the search. That's done via another parameter. There are three possibilities:

   - current level only
   - current level plus one child level
   - entire subtree.
2. The DN you want to search from is specified in another parameter, not in the filter. So the filter string should be merely

   ```
   (sAMAccountName=worker)
   ```

   and the base DN for the search should be

   ```
   ou=grandsongroup,ou=subgroup,ou=maingroup,dc=my,dc=com,dc=app
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question: how in above DN value how to get the value under `grandsongroup`? is `someResultSearch.getAttributes().get("ou").get()`?

Comment: If `ou` is the name of the attribute you want, yes.

Comment: thank you so much. but what if like the example there are three `ou` defined in 3 level but it is required to retrieve the value from grandsongroup?